# Giving the total orderprice of a user without duplicate

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

How could I get my output to show no duplicate of the customer name and show their total order price.

I'm not the best at explaining so I am providing an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
Example
Output that I  don't want
 custno custname custstreet, custcity, orderprice
  001      bob    12 lake dr.  brampton   500.00
  001      bob    12 lake dr.  brampton   500.00

Output: The output I am looking for
 custno custname custstreet, custcity, orderprice
 001      bob    12 lake dr.  brampton   1000.00



  SELECT DISTINCT customer.Custno, Custname, Custstreet, Custcity, Orderprice
    FROM customer, orderprod, orders
    WHERE Custcity = 'Brampton'
    AND customer.Custno = orders.Custno
    HAVING Orderprice >= 500.00;
```

Comment: You have a (potential) redundancy in your design

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about this. any help? If I group by custname it just give me the first value of orderprice for each column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
    SELECT customer.Custno, Custname, Custstreet, Custcity, sum(Orderprice)
      FROM customer, orderprod, orders
     WHERE Custcity = 'Brampton'
       AND customer.Custno = orders.Custno
  GROUP BY customer.Custno, Custname, Custstreet, Custcity
    HAVING sum(Orderprice) > 500.00;
```

Hope that helps....

Comment: give me a in 'having' clause error? any other suggestion. if i remove the the sum from order price it run but return nothing.

Comment: My bad!  I needed the SUM() function around Orderprice in the HAVING clause.  It should work now.  (I corrected the code in my answer, above.)